# NodeJS - fluent-ffmpeg with buffer

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I'm using multer in my backend to achieve file upload. The files are stored in Azure Blob Storage. That's why I just use memoryStorage strategy to avoid files on my filesystem.
When someone upload a video, I want to take a screenshot as Thumbnail before the image will be stored in my Blob Storage.

Fluent ffmpeg accept the following inputs regarding the documentation (https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg):

> You may pass an input file name or readable stream, a configuration
> object, or both to the constructor.
>
> ```
> var command = ffmpeg('/path/to/file.avi');
> var command = ffmpeg(fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file.avi'));
> var command = ffmpeg({ option: "value", ... });
> var command = ffmpeg('/path/to/file.avi', { option: "value", ... });
> ```

I know that I can store the video on my filesystem, and remove it later like that:

```
await fs.writeFileSync(req.files[0].tempName, req.file.buffer);
const ffm = ffmpeg(req.files[0].tempname);
await ffm.thumbnail({
  filename: 'thumbnail.png',
  timemarks: [ '00:00:02.000' ]
});
            
fs.unlinkSync(req.files[0].tempName);
fs.unlinkSync('thumbnail.png');
```

But I want to avoid using the filesystem. So is there any way to resolve this without storing the file on fs?